# Exportar CSV con PHP (fputcsv) no descarga

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

Mi plataforma posee un botón para exportar los datos de una tabla a un archivo CSV. 
Mi código es el siguiente:

```
    $table = 'produ';
    $output_file = 'file.csv';
    $delimiter = ';';
    $enclosure = '"';
    header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset:UTF-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $output_file . '"');
    $h = fopen($output_file, 'w');
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM $table");
    $header_written = false;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        if (! $header_written) {
            fputcsv($h, array_keys($row), $delimiter, $enclosure);    
            $header_written = true;
        }
        fputcsv($h, $row, $delimiter, $enclosure);
    }
    fclose($h);
```

Estas líneas de códigos sí crean el archivo en cuestión. Sin embargo, lo que estoy buscando es que, al hacer click en el botón correspondiente, la descarga del archivo se realice automáticamente.

Vale decir que he podido hacer un a href="" para vincular al archivo en cuestión y descargarlo mediante un mensaje que se muestra al usuario de que el archivo está listo. Sin embargo, conforme se van realizando las exportaciones, los archivos se van acumulando en la carpeta correspondiente. Por ello, lo que deseo es que descargue directamente.

He intentado ya reemplazar la línea...

```
$h = fopen($output_file, 'w');
```

Con...

```
$h = fopen('php://output', 'w');
ob_clean();
...
ob_flush();
```

Ni aún así he logrado la descarga del archivo. Alguna idea?

**EDITO:**

Ya he intentado agregarle un exit(); al final del mismo y no funciona. Tampoco funciona la siguiente línea

```
    $h = fopen('php://memory', 'w');
```

Le he agregado mas headers para ver si así funcionaba, y tampoco...

```
    header("Content-type: application/force-download"); 
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'. $output_file .'"'); 
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
    header("Content-length: ". filesize($output_file)); 
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. $output_file .'"');       
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0
    header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies
```

Comment: La filosofía un poco de esto es generar el CSV en un fichero temporal (ese fichero puede estar en el sistema de archivos o en memoria) y después establecer las caberas de content-type y content-disposition para indicar el tipo de archivo y el nombre del archivo. Hasta ahí vas bien con el primer código que has puesto. Lo que te falta ahora es escribir (echo, printf, etc..) el contenido del fichero CSV en la respuesta que estás generando. https://knackforge.com/blog/vishnu/creating-downloadable-csv-files-php. Ojo también al definir el charset del content-type que estas poniendo : en lugar de =

Comment: Perdón. Mi código al final incluye la setencia readfile($output_file); y lo que ocurre es que el contenido del CSV lo muestre en la página en HTML.

Comment: ¿Tu script está aislado o está incluido en otro? Si escribes unas cabeceras para poder adjuntar un fichero en la respuesta, no puede haber otro script escribiendo otras cabeceras. Pon el código completo porque puede que no estemos viendo el problema porque faltan partes importantes (como lo del readfile)